# Как восстановить загрузку windows 10 после неудачного запуска sysprep

Tags: windows

Для переноса папки с данными профилей пользователей была выполнена команда

```
%windir%\system32\sysprep\sysprep.exe /oobe /reboot /unattend:c:\relocate.xml
```

Содержимое файла relocate.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<unattend xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:unattend">

<settings pass="oobeSystem">

<component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<FolderLocations>

<ProfilesDirectory>E:\Users</ProfilesDirectory>

</FolderLocations>

</component>

</settings>

</unattend>
```

После этих действий загрузка windows останавливается на сообщении об ошибке, после нажатия кнопки OK, компьютер перезагружается и сообщение выводится снова.

```
Не удалось завершить процесс установки. Чтобы установить Windows, перезапустите программу установки.
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: Safe-mode доступен? Либо зайти в режим Recovery, проверить на месте ли профайлы пользователей (C:\Users) и попробовать вырубить sysprep, который (скорее всего) прописался в реестре в ветви HKLM\System\Setup.

Comment: @Daemon-5, если не закрывать окно с предупреждением, можно запустить командную строку сочетанием клавиш shift+f10, папка с профилями пользователей перенеслась частично, как вырубить sysprep?

Comment: Я написал ранее, что искать прописанный автозапуск sysprep можно в ветви реестра **HKLM\System\Setup**. Раз доступна консоль, вызывайте редактор реестра: консольный **reg.exe** или **regedit.exe**. Предполагаю, что надо будет обnullить значение параметра CmdLine.